# How to setup a VM as a router or gateway? (not whonix)

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I want to use a VM as a router or gateway, setting other VM connect to it without setting a `proxy:port` to each software. Then make the router/gateway VM  redirect all the incoming traffic to the specific listening port on the local. How to make these setup?

Comment: You can use `iptables` to achieve your goal. Try `man iptables` to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear what you are asking, it falls in the middle between a proxy and a "classic" router.

In the latter case you will need following steps:

1. Enable forwarding in the kernel `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
2. Enable FORWARD chain (or better specific FORWARD rules) with iptables.
3. Enable SNAT or MASQUERADE in order to NAT internal hosts when they exit your LAN
4. Configure/activate a DHCP server to provide dynamic network
   configuration to hosts, passing your server as gateway.

Comment: I guess these are for the gateway VM, what to do in other VM?

Comment: What is server, is it the gateway VM?

Comment: The proxy software is running on gateway VM.

Comment: 1,2,3,4 are for the gateway VM. Other client don't need configuration as long as gateway VM is also dhcp server of the network providing itself as the gateway of the lan. By the way you need to better clarify terminilogy and goals.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed the problem that I can't communicate with English well, anyhow thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean that, I am not a native speaker of English. I just meant that "proxy" and "gateway" are technically very different concepts.

Comment: The network knowledge are so complicated, I just wanted to make a connection.